# Angular ng-switch-when not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with my ng-switch statement.  I can never get the second condition to fire.  I've verified that SearchDS.maxPages() contains the Max Number of Pages so at some point that section should be printed.

```
<div>
  <div ng-switch="SearchDS.pagingOptions.currentPage">
    <p ng-switch-when="1">1</p>
    
    <p ng-switch-when="{{SearchDS.maxPages()}}">2</p>
    
    <p ng-switch-default>3</p>
  </div
</div>
```

Comment: Haven't used angularjs in many years, but I imagine you should remove the curly brackets from your second ng-switch-when.. like this.. <p ng-switch-when="SearchDS.maxPages()">2</p>

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use expressions inside `ng-switch-when` instead use a function that will perform the switch case internally and exhibit the same behaviour!

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function() {
  this.currentPage = 12;
 this.getValue = () => {
    const secondCase = 12;
    const firstCase = 1;
    switch (this.currentPage) {
      case firstCase:
        return '1';
      case secondCase:
        return '2';
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as $ctrl">
  <div>
    <div ng-switch="$ctrl.getValue()">
      <p ng-switch-when="1">1</p>

      <p ng-switch-when="2">2</p>

      <p ng-switch-default>3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I took the {{ }} brackets out of the statement and when I page through the result set it shows 1 then goes to 3.  So, it's still skipping #2.  From one of the answers it would appear I can't use SearchDS.maxPages() but only a hard-coded value.

Comment: @user3685388 that is why I have given you this solution, you can use `SearchDS.maxPages()` instead of second case variable, no need to hardcode!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the {{}} for that expression.